# Fodor's Lemma for clubs

Tags: set-theory

Fodor's (or *Pressing Down*) Lemma states that for every stationary subset $S$  of a regular cardinal and every regressive function $f:S\to \mathrm{Ord}$, there is an $\alpha$ such that $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ is stationary. Recall that “regressive” means $f(\alpha)<\alpha$ for all $\alpha\neq 0$.

I'm interested in a version concerning clubs instead of stationary sets. Readily,

> Let $C$ be a club in a regular $\kappa$, and let $f$ be regressive, defined on $C$. Is there an $\alpha$ such that $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a club in $\kappa$?

Could you give me a **hint** for this? The only progress I made with this (trying to show it's false) was to prove that every club on  $\kappa$ can be written as the disjoint union of $\kappa$ stationary sets, none of them being a club (these would be my candidates to $f^{-1}(\alpha)$. But I could not come up with a regressive $f$ yet.

In case this is true, I would be interested in a proof that is *simpler* that the one for stationary sets, just for didactical purposes.

---

**Update**: By the comments of GME below, I should make clear that a counterexample must have no $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ as “big” as a club, i.e., in the club filter.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a limit point of $C$, then $C\setminus\{\alpha\}$ is not club in $\kappa$ and neither is $\{\alpha\}$.

Comment: @GME Indeed, but I couldn't find an alternative argument using this idea yet.

Comment: So the argument would be: let $f(\beta) = 0$ for $\beta\in C\setminus\{\alpha\}$ and $f(\beta) = 1$ for $\beta = \alpha$. Then $f$ is regressive, but neither $f^{-1}(0)$ nor $f^{-1}(1)$ is club. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GME Great! Thank you very much. But this argument is not in the _spirit_ of the question, because $f^{-1}(0)$, although not a club, is in the club filter. So, in terms of “size”, is as big as a club.

Comment: Ah, ok; I see. I hadn't realised that was the question.

Comment: Not so sure, since if $\kappa=\omega_2$ then $S_1$ is a club, and if $\kappa$ is greater, then it seems $S_1\cup S_2$ can't be the whole of the club $C$.

Comment: Sorry; that was a typo. Should have been $\kappa = \omega_2$. In that case the ordinals of co-finality $\omega_1$ are not club in $\kappa$ and no club only contains such ordinals. But that's not particularly interesting, so I've deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $C$ as the disjoint union of stationary sets $S_\xi$ for $\xi<\kappa$. Let

$$f:C\to\kappa:\alpha\mapsto\begin{cases}
\xi,&\text{if }\alpha\in S_\xi\text{ and }\alpha>\xi\\
0,&\text{ if }\alpha\in S_\xi\text{ and }\alpha\le\xi\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you prove that $f^{-1}(0)$ is not a club?

Comment: btw, I'm on that right now!

Comment: @Asaf: Consider $S_\omega\setminus(\omega+1)$, for instance.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I noticed that $f^{-1}(0)$ is actually the complement of the diagonal intersection of the $S_\xi$. Is this a hint of how did you find this counterexample?

Comment: @Pedro: No, it just came to me all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm following Brian M. Scott's suggestion and prove that the function he defined actually provides a counterexample.

---

So, write $C$ as a disjoint union $\bigcup_{\xi<\kappa} S_\xi$ of stationary sets. None of them can be a club, since it has empty intersection with the others.

Let  $f:C\to \kappa$ be defined as $f(\alpha) := \xi$ if $\alpha\in S_\xi$ and $\xi<\alpha$, and $0$ otherwise. (Note that in either case exactly one $\xi$ exists.)

If $\xi\neq0$,  $f^{-1}(\xi)$ is included in $S_\xi$, hence not a club. Now,
$$
f^{-1}(0) = \{\alpha\in C : \exists \xi\geq \alpha (\alpha\in S_\xi)\}= \textstyle\bigcup_{\xi<\kappa} S_\xi \cap (\xi+1).
$$
This can't be a club either, since its intersection with each of the stationary $S_\xi$ is bounded.

Comment: I promise I did this before reading Scott's comment! :-)